# C# JsonIgnore hide only one inherited child property from only one derived class

Tags: c#, json.net

My controller:

```
[HttpPost("PostUserTag")]
public async Task<ActionResult<UserTagResponse>> Create(UserDataRequest request)
```

This is my parent:

```
public class UserRequest
{
    public virtual List<int> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

This my child:

```
public class UserDataRequest : UserRequest
{
   [JsonIgnore] 
    public override List<int> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Result - actual output: I can still see my tags in the swagger controller!

```
"": {
    "tags": {
    }
  },
```

Expected output:

```
"": {
    }
```

Note: `UserRequest` is the parent class of many children.

Expected result: that children will override the parent and will ignore the property.

I'm running .NET Core 3.1 with Newtonsoft JSON.NET in this startup configuration:

```
services.AddControllers()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                {
                    // even if it's removed it doesn't work
                    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling=ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                });
```

May help: this is my child:

```
public class UserDataRequest : UserRequest
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "test123")] 
    public override List<int> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

The result would be - actual output:

```
"": {
    "tags": {
    },
   "test123": {
    }
  },
```

Expected output:

```
"": {
   "test123": {
    }
    }
```

In this case it should override tags and not add one more property.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where is the code that you use to generate the JSON?

Comment: I have added an example for the controller

Comment: Should the Tags Property be ignored in every case of UserRequest? Then you could try to place the Attribute on the parent.

Comment: Only in this UserDataRequest child, in all other child this is a valid property

Comment: I retracted my first comment: it seems attributes _are_ inherited. As such, I made a small example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6iArVF). As you can see this example works fine. I will p[lay some more. ps, please @ me when replying, else I will not get notified.

Comment: The fact that your object serializes to `"test123": {}` means that you are not showing your actual code. A list would serialize to `"test123": []`. Please give a [mcve]. Give an **_actual minimal reproducable example_**. We need to be able to reproduce this. Also specify the version of json.net